# Why is Electron painted in black?

Tags: engineering, rocketlab

Falcon 9 is painted white to avoid heating the liquid oxygen.

Why is Electron not also painted white?

Rocket color-related questions:

- [Why parts of RocketLab's Electron become white before launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48273/12102)
- [To what extent, if any, does the exterior paint color of a launch vehicle affect its propellant & vehicle thermal management?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24000/12102)
- [Is the mass of paint relevant in rocket design?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38915/12102)
- [Could a shiny metallic fairing have some engineering advantage? Disadvantage?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20921/12102)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not *painted* black.  It just happens to be that color.  Omitting paint saves weight.  On 2017 May 24, Rocketlab itself [tweeted](https://twitter.com/rocketlab/status/867523393624522753?lang=en):

> Why a black rocket? Carbon composite materials are black! Paint is heavy & adds another process. Plus, doesn't it look beautiful! #ItsaTest

---

A different question would be why other launchers *don't* omit paint.  I found an unsubstantiated claim that RocketLab uses proprietary coatings for its cryogenic tanks.  But it may be just that Electron's relatively small size and thus greater area-to-volume ratio makes paint weight matter more.  Conversely, more area-to-volume means more heat transfer, so insulation matters more.  Or maybe the frost is enough for both insulation and whiteness?  Mere speculation.

Comment: "Black is a good heat-absorbing color. The fuel that SpaceX uses is liquid oxygen that has to be kept at very low temperatures, as a result, they cannot have the whole rocket be black" - says about Falcon 9 în this answer - https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29771/nature-of-the-silky-black-highly-flame-resistant-felt-on-block-5-falcon-9s/45211

Comment: Yet the Electron is Black. So F9 cant be black but Electron can

Comment: @joeJobs SpaceX uses subcooled LOX, so they are, perhaps, more temperature sensitive.  If you use boiling-point LOX, you can just feed the boiloff with no ill effect.

Comment: I've added  [Is the mass of paint relevant in rocket design?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38915/12102) and [Could a shiny metallic fairing have some engineering advantage? Disadvantage?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20921/12102) to the links in the question, you may be able to find additional supporting information in their answers.

Comment: I won't hunt down substantiation for a mere comment, but even on bare aluminum hull *sailboats,* paint mass matters when you're racing.

Comment: Note that the F9 interstage is also black for the same reason: it is not painted and made of carbon composites.

Comment: Maybe Electron body it is made of carbon composites and that is heating mucb less than Falcon 9?